# What happens after a stolen Mac was remotely wiped?

Tags: mac, icloud, security, find-my-mac

A Macbook Air was stolen from us last month and we immediately activated "Find my Mac" and a few minutes later we requested it to be wiped (through iCloud). Today, 1 month later, we received an email saying that the Mac had been wiped (but no location).

My question is: **now what?**

- is there any chance we get a location on the Mac? (i.e. is "Find my Mac" still active? even if OS X is reinstalled?)
- is the Mac usable or is it locked by a pin code? Is it possible to reinstall OS X and use it?

In general, do thieves know what to do with stolen and locked Macs (is it easy to unlock them?), or is it now a brick?

Also the name of the Mac was changed to something generic: "Macbook de mac" (in english: mac's Macbook), which sounds like the thief might have been trying to sell the mac. Now that it has been wiped, could it be because somebody bought it and connected it to a wifi? If it's locked and un-usable, maybe there's a chance that they would bring it to an Apple Store and that we could get it back.

Comment: I have the same doubt, wonder if my stolen laptop is still usable after remote erase/lock.

Answer (score -4):

Yeah u ain't getting it back! Once iCloud is turned off it can't trace like with a phone I factory reset it I don't add iCloud an that tracker the hole thing is factory reset. An that's what a thief would do reinstall it it's easy to get the firmware password. Were u insured? If so talk to Apple about them giving u another one. But straight up truth its long gone.